# How to Update Your own Extension With Command Line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I wanna know how to Update an Extension
i making a code snippet extension and added a new snippet
i used vsce to package the file
this is my extension: "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DylxnTN.bootstrap-all-version-snippet-extension"
i wanna know how i can update the package and make updates to my extension cuz i can't find any tutorials

Comment: use `vsce` to publish your extension and then restart VSC to let it search for updates

Comment: i know how to use vsce
i want to know how to make updates to the extension
anyway i found out how 
but i wanna know how to update the number from 0.0.1 to 1.0.0

Comment: update your `package.json` file or do it with `vsce`